# how to simply load a template into a div kendo

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui

Good Morning guys :)

i'm working on some stuff and i was just wondering what is the method to simply load some html code and add it into a div but without breaking the kendo style, which append with some tests i've done before ...
i've seen some about template but i didn't see a simple way to just load it into a div.

i've tried this but it totaly breaks the css style and event like button ..

```
function panelControler(action){
$.get('templates/search.tpm', function(data) {
    var template = kendo.template(data);
    $("#search").html(template);
});
}
```

in my search.tpm, there are just some html stuff like this

```
 <form action="./index.html">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-style="inset">
      <li>
        <label>Code postal
          <input type="number" id="CP" value="59000" placeholder="" />
        </label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>Pays
          <select id="Country">
            <option value="FR">France</option>
            <option value="ES">Espagne</option>
            <option value="BE">Belgique</option>
            <option value="LU">Luxembourg</option>
          </select>
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div style="text-align:center">  
      <a class="button" data-role="button" onclick="relayControler('usingData')" data-icon="search">Rechecher</a>
      <a class="button" data-role="button" onclick="relayControler('usingPos')" data-icon="search">Autour de ma position</a>
    </div>
  </form>
```

thank you for reading and answering ;)

Comment: Dude, is hard to tell if the rest of the layout will break without knowing it. What you mean by "div kendo" ? What widget it is ?

Comment: the div that will contain the html code above mentionned is this one `<div data-role="view" id="drawer-home" data-layout="drawer-layout" data-title="search">`